# Camel from Tracer to BacklogTracer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I was using Camel 2.19.0 and now I migrated to 2.24.2.

I see that `org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer` has been deprecated and that probably `BacklogTracer` is the way to go.

However, in `Tracer` I had the possibility to set a `TraceEventHandler`, and I'd like to to the same for the `BacklogTracer` so that I can access te `Exchange` object in the three events (*i)* `Exchange` about to be processed, *ii)* `Exchange` about to be processed (in) and *iii)* `Exchange` has been processed (out)) and do some specific actions.

Can someone show an example of how to handle these three events with a BacklogTracer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using the deprecated tracer on Camel 2.x, as it will no be removed. In Camel 3 there is a new tracer implementation where you can implement your custom or extend the default `org.apache.camel.spi.Tracer`.